# Sending XML as URL parament with Javascript Fetch

Tags: javascript

Attempting to use an API that requires XML as one of the paramters.  When the URL is sent, it is encoding the XML parameter, when I need it to NOT encode the XML parameter.

What is being sent is:

`https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=CityStateLookup&XML=%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CCityStateLookupRequest%20USERID%3D%22123456798%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CZipCode%20ID%3D%220%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CZip5%3E45218%3C%2FZip5%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FZipCode%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FCityStateLookupRequest%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20`

This is what I need sent:

`https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?API=CityStateLookup&XML=<CityStateLookupRequest USERID="12345678"><ZipCode ID="0"><Zip5>23272</Zip5> </ZipCode></CityStateLookupRequest>`

How do I remove the encoding from XML parameter?

Content-Type in the header is set to `text/plain`

Javascript function is a ReactJS Hook:

```
export const useZipCodeApi = (zipCode,cityID,stateID) => {    
    const [msgState,msgDispatch] = useContext(MessageContext);
    const fetchData = async() => {        
        let headers = { credentials: "include", method: "get", headers: { 'Content-Type': "text/plain"} }
        const request = `
            <CityStateLookupRequest USERID="${Config.USPS.userID}">
                <ZipCode ID="0">
                    <Zip5>${zipCode}</Zip5>
                </ZipCode>
            </CityStateLookupRequest>        
        `;        
        let api = `${Config.USPS.apiUrl}"${encodeURIComponent(request)}"`;                
        const resp = await fetch(api,{...headers});
        const jsonResp = await resp.text();
        if (jsonResp){
            let xmlData = await jsonResp.xmlData();
            //do something with cityID and stateID
        }
    }
    useEffect(()=>{if(zipCode) fetchData();},[zipCode]);    
}
```

Comment: Why do you need it to not be encoded? Does the server have issues with reading it?

Comment: This for the USPS.  All I know is when I send the URL without the encoded XML it works perfectly.  With the encoded XML, the server responds with an error.

Comment: `Content-type` has no bearing on query parameters. Are you sure you are not supposed to be POSTing that XML?

Comment: Where is the javascript that is being used?

Comment: From the Manual

Client Protocols
HTTP/HTTPS protocols are used for exchange of data. This is to facility passage through
corporate firewalls and inclusion of multiple technologies for implementation. The simple
example of this is a URL in a standard browser of the form:
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll?
API=APINAME&XML=<APINAMEREQUEST USERNAME=’your account’>
<tag>data</tag><tag1>data</tag1></APINAMEREQUEST>

Comment: Is this the documentation you're working from? https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/address-information-api.pdf.

Comment: https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/general-api-developer-guide.pdf

Comment: You commented with the URL from the docs, where is the javascript that you are using?

Comment: Your XML doesn't conform to the spec. Take a look at the sample request in the PDF.

Comment: Posted the JS Code.  If the XML doesn't conform to the spec then how is it I make the request with a decoded XML and I get the proper response?  The two links in my question are the exact same link - one decoded and one encoded.  The decoded one work.  encoded one does not.

Comment: `https%3A%2F%2Fsecure.shippingapis.com%2FShippingAPI.dll`? Is the URL being encoded?

Comment: Oop - posted the wrong URL...I just fixed it.

Comment: What happens when you don't use `encodeURIComponent`?

Comment: The modified URL works just fine. It includes your User ID, too, which you might want to fix.

Comment: Still encodes the XML

Comment: yeah - just noticed that - fixed it as you were probably typing

Comment: Before you fixed it, I highlighted the text, right-clicked and selected "go to URL" and it responded with correct city/state information.

Comment: Hmmm it workked for me as well.  Wonder why it isn't working when I use Javascrpt fetch - that's what is being spit out.

Comment: in API in javascript you are wrapping the XML in double quotes.  **let api = `${Config.USPS.apiUrl}"${encodeURIComponent(request)}"`;** But I don't think the API is expecting the XML to be wrapped in double quotes

Comment: I saw that as well and removed the quotes from around the XML.  Still same results

Comment: OMG - It was a CORS policy issue!  You guys are much appreciated for sticking with me.  I feel like a Horse's A$$ for making such a rookie mistake.